# why bittorrent uses only ~300peers on about 4000?

Tags: windows, bittorrent

I am downloading a file (legal of course).

In the column Peer there is:

```
286 (4078)
```

Why does it use only 300?

In the settings I have:

max connection: 1000
max peer per torrent: 500

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: bittorrnet 7-2 ................

Comment: Is the download rate at maximum? Perhaps BitTorrent doesn't create new connections because it wouldn't improve DL rate.

Comment: Just an fyi, if you have to share your connection with anyone they probably want to kill you for using that many simultaneous connections.  The same applies if you're trying to do other things while the torrents run.

Comment: I don't share my connection. And @joel: now he is downloading at 40kB/s that's pretty slow.

Comment: There's more to throughput than just bandwidth.  There's a lot of overhead on a line involved in processing multiple connections, regardless of how much bandwidth each of those takes up.  A lot of consumer equipment just can't handle it so many, and this is also often a flag used by ISPs to start throttling/traffic shaping.  You might find you get much better performance by drastically cutting down your connection count - say limit yourself to just 50 or even 20.